# Обновление отчета PowerBI из Linux среды

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, powerbi

Всем привет!
Кто то обновляет автоматом отчёты PowerBI находящиеся на сервере on-premise?
Есть возможность обновлять через python скрипт, может есть у кого готовые скрипты?

Comment: Как вы делали, что у вас не получилось? Что пишет, что логах?

Comment: @Sheridan подскажите, при использовании DirectQuery возможно ли настроить авто обновление отчёта на сервере?